# Why are new files on GCP bucket not sending pubsub message?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a bucket on which I have a notification:

```
projects/_/buckets/mybucket/notificationConfigs/11
        Cloud Pub/Sub topic: projects/myproject/topics/NEW_IMAGE_TOPIC
        Filters:
                Event Types: OBJECT_FINALIZE
```

This topic is hooked into a subscription which points to a push endpoint. When I add an image to the bucket nothing happens. To test the topic I send some dummy messages and pull them to a dummy sub. This works OK. At no point do any messages appear in my logs. Should they? Anything else I can check? (I have got this to work in different GCP projects but cannot find any relevant differences).

EDIT: notification created thus:

```
gsutil notification create -f json -t NEW_IMAGE_TOPIC -e OBJECT_FINALIZE %BUCKET%
```

Comment: There is a list of [prerequisites](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes#prereqs) - mainly permissions - are you flowing it?

Comment: How did you create this notification? Do you still have the command?

Comment: Added the notification creation.

Comment: @vitooh thanks possibly not. Much of it is locked down from me. No errors though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was simply the wrong URL for the topic endpoint. Didn't give any error.

Comment: Can you please elaborate where "wrong URL" was configured? As seems from your question, pub sub on dummy messages worked for you.